# rsync - How to copy a certain number of files, pause, repeat

Tags: bash, rsync

I have a situation which I have failed to find a solution for.

I have a process which generates ~10,000 xml files into one directory. Those files get rsync'd (with a delete on the source once copied) to a server which runs a process every 5 minutes to import them. The problem is that the volume of files is such that it takes longer than 5 minutes to process them and I can't change that timing. What I would like to do is come up with a script which would allow me to rsync the first 2500 files in the directory, wait 5 minutes, rsync the next 2500, etc. The numbers of files vary, so I'd want it to just keep going through until all the files have been copied. The order of the files doesn't matter, they could be listed alphabetically or by date or just random. Does anyone have any examples of how to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly your problem, you need something like:

```
while true; do
    ls | shuf -n 2500 > /tmp/sync_files # pick random files
    rsync -av `cat /tmp/sync_files` /destination/  # sync the files
    xargs rm < /tmp/sync_files # delete the files
    sleep 300; # sleep 5 minutes
done
```

In the code you pick random files, synced in another directory, then remove them (if the files contain spaces or some weird characters it shall be done with a for loop and then `rm` command, and finally sleep 5 seconds. Let me know if I got your problem right.

Comment: Instead of the `xargs rm..` why not just add `--remove-source-files` to rsync?

Answer (score 0):

Randomness is optional and we want to stop when the files are transmitted. Using the output of `ls` sometimes gives strange results So that would make it:

```
#!/bin/bash
qty=2500
sleeptime=300

typeset -i i
i=0

for f in * ; do
    rsync -av "$f" /destination/
    rm $f
    i=$i+1
    if [ $i = $qty ] ; then
        sleep $sleeptime
        i=0
    fi
done
```

But then you do an rsync per file, which may also not be what you want.